# List item field value has ID and # prepended

Tags: spgridview, spsitedataquery

I want to display a list of items with name and modified time, like so:

```
  SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

  SPWebCollection webs = thisWeb.Webs;

  SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
  query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType=\"1\" />";
  query.ViewFields = 
      "<FieldRef Name=\"Modified\" Nullable=\"true\" />" +
      "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\" Nullable=\"true\" />";

  DataTable table = thisWeb.GetSiteData(query);

  BoundField modified = new BoundField();
  modified.DataField = "modified";
  modified.HeaderText = "Modified";

  BoundField name = new BoundField();
  name.DataField = "FileLeafRef";
  name.HeaderText = "Namn";

  GridView.Columns.Add(name);
  GridView.Columns.Add(modified);

  GridView.DataSource = table;
  GridView.DataBind();
```

The resulting table looks like this:

```
1;#CSS       2012-06-12 08:58:45
7;#Images    2012-06-12 08:58:45
```

Can anyone tell me why Sharepoint is prepending what looks like the ID of the object?

The behaviour is especially preplexing because accessing the field via PowerShell looks ok:

```
> $web.Lists[1].Items[0]["FileLeafRef"]
  posten_intranet_base.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Why? My best guess is... inside views SharePoint can use the ID to build a URL to the item.

To fix your issue, it will probably be easiest for you to just iterate over the DataTable rows and trim off the `id;#`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.
[ok, now I now that return sends the comment..]
This behaviour strikes me as really unconvenient. Perhaps a better question would be "how would I go about achieving this without resorting to hackish methods like the one suggested in your answer?"

Comment: Woops sorry, I didn't realize you had commented until now. Why is it a hack? If it works... it works. :P

Comment: Yes, your solution works. I ended up using it.
But my point is that the proper way to do it would be to give the programmer some way of accessing the value of a field directly, without the meta data.

Answer (score 0):

From the code available here it seems FileLeafRef column is a lookup column.

```
new SPFieldLookupValue(item["FileLeafRef"] as String).LookupValue
```

This will display only the text.